# How can I help an Area 51 proposal advance from commitment to beta?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I had a look at the Science Fiction entry on Area 51, which is in the commit phase. It seems to be stuck in development hell, for 6 months perhaps. I don't know if your approval also has stalled, but these sites like Science Fiction Stack Exchange could be excellent, if pushed. It needs to be progressed somehow. Good sites like Science Fiction on Stack Exchange could be the new voice of Science Fiction on the web.

Comment: "It needs progressed somehow.", well, that is the job of the audience of that community. The more supporters you gain, the faster it will reach the next stage.

Comment: I have the slight impression that you misinterpreted the actual meaning of the word "development" in the Area 51 context. It should not come from the side of Stackexchange, but from the side of the committers.

Answer (score 21):

**You** need to commit to the proposal (if you haven't already), then **you** need to publicise the site through Facebook, Twitter, your own blog etc., using the referrer link, to encourage more people to commit.

Once enough people (which depends on their reputation across **all** Stack Exchange sites) have committed it will move to private and then public beta.

**You** can also participate in other existing sites yourself which will boost your own reputation and increase the commit percentage.

So what are **you** waiting for?

The point is, is that if not enough committed people want the site then there's every possibility it will fail, the Area 51 process is designed to find those sites that will work *in the long term*.